# Why is it true that when the coefficients of the polynomial are real numbers, This process will be established

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We now consider the polynomial with real coefficients:
$$
f(z)=a_0 z^n+a_1 z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_{n-1} z+a_n,
$$
and we suppose that it has a complex zero $z=a+b i \quad(b \neq 0)$ of order of multiplicity $k$, i.e.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& f(a+b i)=f^{\prime}(a+b i)=\ldots=f^{(k-1)}(a+b i)=0 ;(1) \\
& f^{(k)}(a+b i)=A+B i \neq 0 . (2)
\end{aligned}
$$
We now replace all the quantities in $f(a+b i)$ and its derivatives by their conjugates. The real coefficients $a_s$ will remain unchanged in this process.

My question is: why does this process remain unchanged when $a_s$ is a real number; correspondingly, what happens to this process when $a_s$ is a complex number

Comment: Hint: see what happens when trying to express $f(\bar{z})$ in terms of $z$.

Comment: @Bruno B,I know that substituting $\overline{z}$, (1) and (2) hold, but I want to know why $a_{s}$ needs to be a real number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at your polynomial $f(z) = a_n z^n + a_{n-1} z^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 z + a_0$ (different indices).

You seem to understand that $f(\overline{z}) = \overline{f(z)}$ if the $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$. (If not trying showing this first). This implies that for every root of a polynomial with real coefficients the complex conjugation is also a root.

One way to argue why this doesn't work with complex coefficients is by looking at a counterexample:

> Consider the example:
> $$g(x) = (1+i)x -2$$
> This polynomial obviously has complex coefficients. One of the roots is $1-i$ since $(1+i)(1-i) = 2$. As such $g(1-i) = 0$.
> However $g(\overline{1-i})=g(1+i) = (1+i)(1+i) -2 = 1+2i-1-2 = -2 +2i \neq \overline{g(1-i)} = \overline{0} = 0$

Comment: Oh I understand, because $\overline{a z}=\bar{a} \bar{z}$, so if you want to put the overline of $\overline{f(z)}$ above z, you need $\overline {a}=a$, so a can only be a real number

Answer (score 3):

We have:
$$f(\bar{z}) = \sum_{j = 0}^d a_j \bar{z}^j = \sum_{j = 0}^d \overline{\overline{a_j} z^j} = \overline{\sum_{j = 0}^d \overline{a_j} z^j} =: \overline{\hat{f}(z)}$$
where I introduce the (nonstandard) notation $\hat{f}$ to use it afterwards.
If $a_j$ is real for all $j$, then we obtain $\hat{f}(z) = f(z)$ at the end, hence $f(\bar{z}) = 0 \Leftrightarrow f(z) = 0$.
This will also work if all the $a_j$s are all "aligned" in the sense that they're of the form $b_j z_0$ for a fixed $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}^*$ of modulus $1$ and real $b_j$s, as we'd have
$$\hat{f}(z) = \displaystyle\frac{\overline{z_0}}{z_0} f(z) = \frac{1}{z_0^2}f(z)$$
leading to the same conclusion.
Reciprocally, if $\hat{f} = \beta f$ for some $\beta \in \mathbb{C}^*$, then it's easy to see that $\beta$ must be of modulus $1$ (by looking at the moduli in $\overline{a_j} = \beta a_j$ with a nonzero $a_j$), and then you can define $\displaystyle\frac{1}{z_0}$ by taking one of its square roots such that the $a_j$s are "$z_0$-aligned": indeed, if we have $\bar{a_j} = \beta a_j$ for a nonzero $a_j$, then, by multiplying by $a_j$ on both sides we have
$$|a_j|^2 = \beta a_j^2$$
hence $\displaystyle\frac{a_j^2}{|a_j|^2} = \beta^{-1} = z_0^2$, meaning that $a_j = \pm|a_j|z_0$, which is exactly what I defined as "$z_0$-aligned" once we take into account the $a_j$s which were equal to $0$.

But in the case of there being at least one non-aligned $a_j$, there is no such certainty to your claim.
Since the functions $z \mapsto f^{(k)}(\bar{z})$ will have respectively the same roots as $\widehat{f^{(k)}} = (\hat{f})^{(k)}$, the $f^{(k)}$s cannot all have their roots be conjugate, as that would mean that $\hat{f} = \alpha f$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}^*$ due to having the same roots with the same multiplicities, yet we have $\hat{f} \neq \beta f$ for any $\beta \in \mathbb{C}^*$ by assumption and by what precedes.
This implies that the roots are not conjugate for at least one $f^{(k_0)}$, hence not guaranteeing that conjugate roots will have the same multiplicity nor that you'll even have all the roots be conjugate.